# How to find the number of elements in a particular column of a 2 dimensional array in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

For a given 2d matrix of size m X n i need to find the number of elements present in every column.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? In it's current state this question is entirely unclear

Comment: @Paul he wants to know the number of elements of his columns.

Comment: @TomWellbrock that doesn't define anything relevant for solving the problem. E.g. what is considered an element? Do `null`-values count? Or for floating-point numbers, what about NaN? This question is lacking way to much information to even be answerable. Have a look at the answer. It's a mere guess on what the question even means.

Comment: @Paul consider only characters and numbers

Comment: @Paul I answere in regard to the question. elements are all possible valuesof an set (including null or NaN). Thats the definition of element. The answere might not help him, but it answeres the question.

Comment: @TomWellbrock how do you know that without seeing the question?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, the number of elements present in a given column is the number of rows, no ? Anyway...

```
int rows = matrix.length;
int cols = matrix[0].length;
```

Comment: what if every doesn't contain same number of elements?and your solution will tell  how many elements are there in a given row which is not what i wanted

Comment: cols=matrix[0].length()  will give how many elements are there in that particular row what i want is how many elements are there in every column because every row can have different number of elements  did u get my point?

Comment: You said you have a matrix with size M x N . by definitiion, if it's a matrix, all collumns and rows have the same size.

What you have maybe is an array of arrays.

Comment: yeah its an array of arrays at that time yours solution doesn't work.